# Differentiate a div for css

Tags: html, css, popupwindow

I've created a pop-up window content box that contains a video. Now, when I refer to my Modal div in my css the video also gets affected. Is there any way I can differentiate the two? Fixing this issue would make me able to refer the video in the css (.video) and the content-box (modal), while the video still is a apart of the window pop-up (so that it works with my @media etc.)

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  
<style>
    
  /* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #0E0E0E;
  margin: 15% auto; 
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}

</style>
<body>
    <dialog>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <video
        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/videos/c/o/v/1ef399dd4bb345e485f6e4784a9d0031.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"
        autoplay
      ></video>
    </dialog>
  </body>
  <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.querySelector('dialog');

    var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

    btn.onclick = function () {
      modal.showModal();
    };

    span.addEventListener('click', e => modal.close());
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: add the css to video to counteract the css in the modal. also look into :not()

Comment: Hello, I've only coded for a little less then 1 week, how would this be done?

Edit: I've tried typing .video {} in my <style> but it doesn't work